# restoreCompletedTransactions() not calling paymentQueue updatedTransactions?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, skpaymenttransaction

I am having trouble restoring an IAP in Swift 4/iOS 11. My `AppDelegate` implements `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`. In `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I'm calling `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)`. I implement the `paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])` function in AppDelegate as well.

From a `ViewController` I can make a purchase like so:

```
let payment = SKPayment(product: products.first!)
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
```

The purchase finishes successfully - I get an `updatedTransaction` with state `.purchased` in my `paymentQueue` observer.

However, when I call the following from this same `ViewController` in order to restore the purchase:

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
```

the `paymentQueue updatedTransactions` function is never called.

It seems like my sandbox user, etc. is set up correctly since the initial purchase is working. Do sandbox users have the ability to restore purchases? Do I need to do any additional work besides calling `restoreCompletedTransactions()` to restore purchases?

---

Update, here is my `paymentQueue updatedTransactions` code that lives in `AppDelegate`:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions{
        switch transaction.transactionState{
        case .purchased:
            debugPrint("purchased it!")
            menuDelegate?.unlockMenu()
            //unlock the content, then
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            break
        case .failed:
            debugPrint("failed")
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            break
        case .restored:
            debugPrint("restored")
            menuDelegate?.unlockMenu()
            //unlock the content, then
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            break
        case .purchasing:
            debugPrint("purchasing...")
            break
        case .deferred:
            debugPrint("deferred...")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are completing the transaction correctly?  Can you show your updatedTransactions code?

Comment: I edited my updatedTransactions into the question. I have tried it with and without the `break` in each `case` - didn't seem to make a difference either way.

Comment: It shouldn't matter but you should say `queue.finishTransaction` rather than `SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction`